# Python float and integer values to bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, byte

I am working on sending data to another program via serial communication.

This receiver program accepts 78 bytes arrays and, each data must be in its own dedicated byte index for the receiver to understand.

Ex: I have an integer altitude value=2500

and the program accepts 4-byte integer values. So I need to fit this integer to these bytes

I wrote a code like this:

```py
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM16', 19200, serial.EIGHTBITS, serial.PARITY_NONE, serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

size = 78
array1 = bytearray(size)

altitude=2800.0


check_sum = 0

array1[0] = 0xFF
array1[1] = 0xFF
array1[2] = 0x54
array1[3] = 0x52
array1[4] = 15
array1[5] = 27
array1[6] = 0
array1[7] = 0
array1[8] = 0
array1[9] = 0
array1[10] = 0
array1[11] = 0
array1[12] = 0
array1[13] = 0
array1[14] = 0
array1[15] = 0
array1[16] = 0
array1[17] = 0
array1[17] = 0
array1[19] = 0
array1[19] = 0
array1[20] = 0
array1[21] = 0
array1[22] = 0
array1[23] = 0
array1[24] = 0
array1[25] = 0
array1[26] = 0
array1[27] = 0
array1[28] = 0
array1[29] = 0
array1[30] = 0
array1[31] = 0
array1[32] = 0
array1[33] = 0
array1[34] = 0
array1[35] = 0
array1[36] = 0
array1[37] = 0
array1[38] = 0
array1[39] = 0
array1[40] = 0
array1[41] = 0
array1[42] = 0
array1[43] = 0
array1[44] = 0
array1[45] = 0
array1[46] = 0
array1[47] = 0
array1[48] = 0
array1[49] = 0
array1[50] = 0
array1[51] = 0
array1[52] = 0
array1[53] = 0
array1[54] = 0
array1[55] = 0
array1[56] = 0
array1[57] = 0
array1[58] = 0
array1[59] = 0
array1[60] = 0
array1[61] = 0
array1[62] = 0
array1[63] = 0
array1[64] = 0
array1[65] = 0
array1[66] = 0
array1[67] = 0
array1[68] = 0
array1[69] = 0
array1[70] = 0
array1[71] = 0
array1[72] = 0
array1[73] = 0
array1[74] = 1

array1[76] = 0x0D
array1[77] = 0x0A

for x in range(4, 75):
    check_sum += array1[x]

check_sum % 256

array1[75] = check_sum

ser.write(array1)
```

The first 4 bytes and last 2 bytes are constant to receive the requirements

My question is

```py
altitude=2800

array1[6] = 0
array1[7] = 0
array1[8] = 0
array1[9] = 0
```

these 4 bytes are reserved to keep altitude data.

how can I put this altitude data in an array with these byte values?

Comment: what result do you expect in array for `2800`  - `0, 0, 10, 240` or `240, 10, 0, 0` - ie, `array1[6:10] = struct.pack('i', altitude)` or use `"<i"` or `">i"` to change order

Comment: you have to assign new value `check_sum = check_sum % 256` or use `%=` like `check_sum %= 256` but shorter will be `check_sum = sum(array1[4:75]) % 256`

Comment: I'm not sure but `bytearray(size)` should create array already with zeros and there is no need to set zeros manually `array1[6] = 0`

Comment: yes as you said I removed zeros and worked

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html). It is specifically designed to address what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Niko's answer, this problem can be solved with Python's builtin [struct library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html). However, you don't seem to have specified anything about the required byte order of your application. For example, the following expressions would produce different results:

```
big_endian = struct.pack(">f", 0.24)
little_endian = struct.pack("<f", 0.24)

print([*big_endian]) # [62, 117, 194, 143]
print([*little_endian]) # [143, 194, 117, 62], the order is reversed
```

You should check your receiver requirement of endianness and use the appropriate one in your Python script.

Comment: How can I beautify it by making it a struct

Comment: @InertialMeasurementUnit I don't understand your comment, what do you mean by beautifying the program?
In Python there is no concept of struct. The package is named `struct` because it deals with the struct packing/padding concept in the lower C/C++ level. We just happen to use a very small functionality of this package to convert data to bytestring. 
I would recommend reading more about the way data is represented on memory in C/C++ and subsequently Python.